# I'm trying to make a small calculator in C++ but it only calculates scientific notations

Tags: c++, numbers, calculator

I'm new to C++ and to start off I'm making a multiplication calculator. The problem is whenever I do numbers over ~1000 it just calculates scientific notations. The code is below, can anyone help?

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float value;
    cout << "Please enter value ";
    cin >> value;
    float multBy;
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to multiply by? ";
    cin >> multBy;
    float answer = value * multBy;
    cout << "\nYour answer is " << answer;
    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: *it just calculates scientific notations* -- No, it is *displaying* scientific notation.  The goal is to format the display correctly (`iomanip`, `std::format`, etc.).

Comment: Can you show me an example on how iomanip works?

Answer (score 0):

The following is modified code of yours. By the use of showpoint and fixed , the results are displayed in fixed point notation and by the use of "setprecision" we can adjust the numbers after decimal in result.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   float value;
    cout << "Please enter value ";
    cin >> value;
    float multBy;
    cout << "\nWhat would you like to multiply by? ";
    cin >> multBy;
    float answer = value * multBy;
    cout << "\nYour answer is " <<showpoint<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<answer;
    system("pause>0");
}
```